# Does parse PFUser download all User object columns content?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a User class in Parse that contains a profilePicture along with some other User info. I couldn't figure out if when I run a query in Swift and Parse returns the PFUser object, does that object already contain the profilePicture or does it download it when I use

```
PFUser.currentUser()?["profilePicture"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The object only contain the profilePicture as a PFFile (PFFile representes a file of binary data stored on the Parse servers). You are simply accessing the PFFile which is by indexing with ["profilePicture"].

To get the actual profilePicture when you use it, you can do something like the following to turn the PFFile into UIImage and display it out.

```
let imageFile = listingObjectPassed["imageFile"] as! PFFile
        imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                self.imagePic.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm concerned because I'm trying to optimize my app. If my page takes a long time to load is it more likely because there is PFFile or because I'm converting it to an image? I have a profilePicture and a thumbnail and I would only be displaying the thumbnail, would that help since as you said if would still download the profilePicture as PFFile?

Comment: When you get the user object you only get PFFile. PFFile is not the actual image. PFFile contains the name of the file, the url of the file on Parse server, and the dirty bit (use to keep track if the file has been edit/change). Hence, your page will not takes a long time to load because there is PFFile. (PFFile is an explicit reference to an object in the Parse data store). You actually do work and download the file (picture, movie, etc.) when you call getDataInBackgroundWithBlock in the code shown above